# MYSQL Trigger to insert column value in same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a mysql Innodb table 'classrooms_subjects' as

```
id|classroom_id|subject_id
```

classroom_id & subject_id are composite keys. Whenever i insert a row with classroom_id & subject_id, my id field is inserted as 0.

Now i want to create a trigger which will enter id field as last_inserted_id()+1.

Also I need to take care of multiple records inserted at a time. My trigger is like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `increment_id` AFTER INSERT ON `classrooms_subjects`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE classrooms_subjects
SET classrooms_subjects.id = LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1 WHERE id=0;
END
```

when i am inserting a record I am getting the error as:
"Cant update table in trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this trigger

Comment: Use an `auto_increment` column.

Comment: 2 columns comprises of composite keys hence mysql doesnt allow to create another column as autoincrement

Comment: You can define an auto-increment column as the primary key and the pair as a unique, non-null key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general info: using an update statement inside the trigger isn't right.

Better to use a before insert trigger and simply assign the value of your column using NEW.id

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

> A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have
>   the SELECT privilege), but not modify it. **You can refer to a column
>   named with NEW if you have the SELECT privilege for it. In a BEFORE
>   trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value
>   if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a
>   trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to
>   update a row.** (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER
>   trigger because the row change will have already occurred.)

You should probably structure your table to make the auto_increment work properly. Better a solution that works when multiple sessions are inserting to the DB at once.